# why are those comparisons giving me a different answer when they are mathematically the same in C?

Tags: c, comparison

```
char s[]="hello";
int i=5;
if(5>strlen(s)-i-1) printf("ok");
if(5>5-i-1) printf("ok2");
```

the output of the program above will be ok2 which is weird because the values of the conditions are the same and i can't figure out why it doesn't go inside the first if statement.

Comment: `strlen(s)` is unsigned, which affects the computation. `strlen(s)-i-1` is `4294967295` on my 32-bit compiler, which isn't `< 5`.

Comment: To get the same result for both conditions you would need to use `5u` instead of `5`.

Comment: Mandatory read: [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Comment: Avoid subtraction and negative values when working with _unsigned_ math.  `(5>strlen(s)-i-1` --> `(5 + i + 1) > strlen(s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware of the rules for usual arithmetic conversions.

In an expression like `a-b` the operand with "smaller" type is converted to the type of the other operand.

Here "smaller" does not necessarily mean less bits but refers to a given order of types: unsigned types > signed types, long types > short types, floating point types > integer types.

In your cases you have `int` and `size_t` which normally is `unsigned int` (or `unsigned long`).

With this in your mind, your 2 conditions will look a bit different.

`5 - i - 1` is of type `int` as each of the operands are of type `int`.
The result is `-1` and `5 > -1` is `true`.

In `strlen(s) - i - 1` all operands will be converted to `size_t` which means the result is `(size_t) -1` which evaluates to `2<<32-1` or `0xFFFFFFFF` for 32 bit values. Now `5 > 0xFFFFFFFF` is `false`.

This is why you get different results for your different conditions.

To get the same result you need to make `5` unsigned, too. That can be achieved by using `5u` instead.

Comment: "strlen(s) - i - 1 all operands will be promoted to unsigned int" needs refinement.  `size_t`, the type returned by `strlen()`, may be some other _unsigned_ type.

Comment: These are the *usual arithmetic conversions*, not promotions. Promotions are conversions that **never change the value**; they only widen the type. E.g., a `signed char` may be promoted to `int`, but it is never promoted to `unsigned int`. Individual operands may be promoted, as when `char` is promoted to `int`. When finding a common type for multiple operands, then the *usual arithmetic conversions* are applied. The *integer promotions* are a subset of the *usual arithmetic conversions*.

Comment: Also, the usual arithmetic conversions do not always convert the “smaller” type to to the type of the other operand. Given a `uint64_t` and a 32-bit `float`, the 64-bit `uint64_t` is converted to 32-bit `float`. Or, given a 32-bit `long` and a 32-bit `unsigned int`, both operands are converted to `unsigned long`.

Comment: With "smaller" I didn't mean "less bits". Adding all the details might be a bit above the level of the OP.